# Vertically aligning div using CSS and Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to build a simple survey with 10 questions which are stored in my database, looped through and the 10 questions are added to the page dynamically. Basically, I would like there to only be one question on the page at a time, but the page to be scrollable to see the other questions.

For example, question 1 would show up in the middle of the page, the user types their answer and clicks next, and the page scrolls to the next question. If the user scrolls up, it scrolls through the page up, and down scrolls down. For jumping to the next question I was planning on just having each question with an id and the next button just having a link to that id.

My HTML for populating the questions on the page looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row wrapper">
        <div class="question">
            <p>What is your name?</p>
        </div>

        <div class="description">
            <p>Used for...</p>
        </div> 

        <div class="answer">
            <input type="text" placeholder="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS for the above looks like this:

```
.question {
    color: #232A33;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 2em;
}

.description {
    color: #FFCD3D;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 1.25em;
}

.answer {
    color: #232A33;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 1.25em;
}
```

I managed to get the question centered on the page using the following code:

```
.wrapper {
    width: 500px;
    height: 150px;

    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;

    margin: auto;
}
```

This works fine for one question, but if there are multiple questions they all overlap each other because the position is absolute.

Any tips on how I can achieve this design for the page?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close. This can be done by adding just a tad more css in (adjusting the row class slightly).

If you add the following:

```
.row {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 15% auto;
  height: 100vh!important;
}
```

and adjust your wrapper to `**relative**` positioning, you should see a good result

```
.wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
}
```

See snippet or [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/yrh49avp/)

```css
.question {
  color: #232A33;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.description {
  color: #FFCD3D;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 1.25em;
}

.answer {
  color: #232A33;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 1.25em;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 15% auto;
  height: 100vh!important;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row wrapper">
    <div class="question">
      <p>What is your name?</p>
    </div>

    <div class="description">
      <p>Used for...</p>
    </div>

    <div class="answer">
      <input type="text" placeholder="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row wrapper">
    <div class="question">
      <p>What is your name?</p>
    </div>

    <div class="description">
      <p>Used for...</p>
    </div>

    <div class="answer">
      <input type="text" placeholder="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row wrapper">
    <div class="question">
      <p>What is your name?</p>
    </div>

    <div class="description">
      <p>Used for...</p>
    </div>

    <div class="answer">
      <input type="text" placeholder="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row wrapper">
    <div class="question">
      <p>What is your name?</p>
    </div>

    <div class="description">
      <p>Used for...</p>
    </div>

    <div class="answer">
      <input type="text" placeholder="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! That works great. While I was still looking for my own solution on Saturday I came across the Bootstrap ScrollSpy which seems to also do something similar to what I am after. https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_scrollspy.asp . Do you know if there is a benefit of one approach over the other?

Comment: @user2573690 there's not especially any real benefit; it's just a different library with a bit more css.. but why bother if you can fix it yourself ;)

Comment: @user2573690 actually now i come to think of it, I've used the scrollspy once, and found it a bit buggy and tbh, a bit of a pain in the ass.. stick to the original.. that's my own humble opinion.. but feel free to explore!

Comment: Hi again, quick question, I've been playing around with the layout and added some larger questions with multiple options...is there a way to keep these centered? In the example above I had very similar sized questions so it worked great but it doesn't seem to center vertically dynamically. I've played a bit with the margins, but that doesn't seem to do it. Any ideas?

Comment: For a Start you should never use absolute positioning, if you left it in the code you're going to have problems.  Use relative position and set margin to auto or 0 auto and you should be fine. I set it to 15% auto to give margin at top and bottom of 15% but you can remove this and just leave it at auto. (You should really ask a new q in future if you have another q, its 2:53 am here, I just woke up by fluke)